# What if child process blocked, how to stop parent?

Tags: c, linux, multiprocessing, fork

I have to run my processes in strong order, child then parent, what if child gets blocked, how to stop parent?

```
if ((pid = fork()) == -1) { /* create a child process */
    perror("fork() failed\n");
    exit(1);
}
if (pid == 0) {
    /* child process */
    func1(NULL);

    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
} else {
    /* parent process */
    wait(NULL);
    func2(NULL);

    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the `wait()` block for you?

Comment: @thebusybee I mean what if with child gets blocked and I will be waiting for blocked child process, how to stop waiting it, I don know how to formulate it differently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aaand as an alternative to an active cpu-busy loop with a timeout doing `waitpid()` with `WNOHANG` in a loop, you should prefer to implement it in such a way that cpu is free.

Do not call `wait` from parent, instead enable `SIGCHLD` and setup timeout with a timer and call `pause()` and wait for and dispatch events from signals with `pause()`. An example how to do it is even in [`man 3 wait`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wait.3p.html).

Also on Linux you can use `pidfd_open(pid, 0)` and call `poll()` on it for `POLLIN` with a timeout.

Answer (score 1):

From the comment you gave: You don't want to stop the parent on a blocked child, which is done by `wait()`. In contrary, you don't want the parent to be blocked in `wait()`.

Use `waitpid()` for this. It receives a third argument, which can include `WNOHANG`. This will make `waitpid()` return immediately, without waiting for some child to change its state. However, you need to implement some kind of loop, a check for desired states, and probably a timeout.

For further information please consult the documentation.